# ExtJS : datefield showing up as blank on selection of a grid row

Tags: extjs, extjs4

This is a wierd problem that I am seeing. I populate my store and then the Grid using that store. Also, i used loadRecord(record) to populate a form ( Ext.form.Panel ) basing on the row selected in the Grid. One of the fields in my Ext.form.Panel is:

```
xtype: 'datefield',
readOnly: true,
fieldLabel: 'End Date',
name: 'soEndDate',
id:'soEndDateField',
format: 'm/d/Y'
```

My problem is this date field shows up as blank. I am getting the data right into the store. Because if I change the xtype to 'textfield', I can see the date in this format: 2014-01-30T05:00:00Z. And again the moment I turn back the xtype to 'datefield', the date is gone again !!!

I have literally been banging my head on this for a couple of hours now and I am not sure what kind of blunder have I been doing. I hope someone would respond to this at the earliest :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the format of the date 'soEndDate' coming in from your record?  Is it '2014-01-30T05:00:00Z'?

If that's the case then the datefield doesn't know what to do with it. Either:

1) Change your format to

```
format: 'c'
```

2) Add to altFormats

```
altFormats: '"m/d/Y|n/j/Y|n/j/y|m/j/y|n/d/y|m/j/Y|n/d/Y|m-d-y|m-d-Y|m/d|m-d|md|mdy|mdY|d|Y-m-d|n-j|n/j|c

// c being the key here.
```

Comment: got the answer in the meanwhile. Like you said, it was not knowing what to do with that string. So, in the Ext.data.Model definition, I specified that it is a date:
    {name: 'soEndDate', type: 'date'}
And that worked. Thanks a lot for coming to my resue though. Appreciate it. Accepting the answer as well :)

Comment: Yeah, as long at you put a date string in the combo it needs to be in proper format. If you have an actual Date Object, it doesn't matter what the format is for the combobox. :)

Comment: That's true and hence better defining in the Model itself that it's a date, and not a String. Thanks buddy.